# Spring MVC | IBM Websphere Application Server | Server Startup Error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websphere

I am getting the following error while deploying a Spring MVC app on IBM WAS 6.1.

```
[17/07/13 12:31:55:466 BST] 0000001a WebApp        E   Exception caught while initializing context 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0':
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter]:
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException:
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl incompatible 
with javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
            at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:917)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:378)
            at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:338)
            at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.addWebApplication(WebGroup.java:93)
            at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost.addWebApplication(VirtualHost.java:162)
            at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApp(WebContainer.java:673)
            at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApplication(WebContainer.java:626)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:395)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:611)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1274)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1164)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:591)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:831)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:945)
            at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$AppInitializer.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2120)
            at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:342)
            at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1551)
```

Same application works fine on Tomcat + Eclipse. But when I deployed this on IBM WAS 6.1 using Rational Application Developer I get this error during server startup.

Could any please help me in resolving this error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a library from WAS is incompatible with a library used by your application.

Comment: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?139513-Problem-with-SpringWS-and-JBoss-AS6

Answer (score 3):

This is a class loader issue and looks very similar to [XSLT ClassCastException in WebSphere when Spring tries to create an AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573179/xslt-classcastexception-in-websphere-when-spring-tries-to-create-an-annotationme)

So try setting the class loader policy to PARENT_LAST and remove all dependencies on xml-apis / xerces / javax.xml jars from your application.

Comment: I am just using xalan.jar and if I remove this then I start getting `Provider for com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl is not found` error.

Comment: Are you using classes from the xalan.jar directly in your application? If so, be sure you're instantiating everything correctly (via `TransformerFactory`, etc.) Otherwise, you can change the default `TransformerFactory` implementation by setting the `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` system property.

Comment: Do you know how can I set the system property javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory in Websphere application server and which implementation would be compatible with javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory

Comment: Try adding this to your web.xml `<system-property javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory="org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>`

Comment: I just checked the class hierarchy for `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl`. It extends `javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXTransformerFactory` which in turn extends `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory ` why is the server throwing ClassCastException then?

Comment: I just tried to change the Transformer implementation and I get same incompatible error with this implementation as well. I don't understand they fall in same class hierarchy how can we get ClassCastException then.

Comment: There are two instances of `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl`. One included in the WAS 6.1 JVM and another in the xalan.jar file. When your application starts up it's loading the `TransformerFactoryImpl` from the jar file, but the JVM is expecting the one that's included with it instead.

Comment: Agree with you but the point is as soon as I remove xalan.jar, server throws me no provider found error. So basically it isn't picking up the WAS 6.1 JVM jar file. How can I make sure that my application picks up the jar file from WAS JVM.

Comment: Yes, that seems odd to me, once the xalan.jar is removed it should be picking it up from the WAS JVM automatically. Maybe try setting the class loader policy to PARENT_FIRST as well.